# как сейчас правильно убрать StatusBar

Tags: flutter, dart

Как сейчас правильно убрать StatusBar? Раньше это делалось так:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

Сейчас метод **setEnabledSystemUIOverlays()** является устаревшим.

> @Deprecated('Migrate to setEnabledSystemUIMode. ' 'This feature was
> deprecated after v2.3.0-17.0.pre.')

Подскажите, как сейчас (SDK Flutter 2.5.3) убрать StatusBar?

Comment: Наверное вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69326385/5479247

Comment: Уважаемый  Eugene Krivenja! Огромное Вам спасибо! Сделайте это, как ответ, что бы можно было засчитать вопрос.

Comment: SystemUiOverlay.bottom  там нужно немножко подправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `setEnabledSystemUIMode` чтобы с помощью `SystemUiMode.manual` вручную настроить нужные элементы:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
  SystemUiOverlay.top
]);
```

Можно использовать заготовки `SystemUiMode`
Скрыть панели статуса и навигации (будут появляться по свайпу):

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
```

Отобразить панели статуса и навигации:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
```

Документация: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiMode-class.html
Оригинал ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69326385/5479247